# setting line height for text that runs over two or more lines

Tags: html, css

I'm currently formatting my website for viewing on mobile and I can't see how I can set the line height of text within a div when the text runs over two lines but has not had a line break applied.

Here is my current css...

```
#ProjectName {
font-family: "helvetica_roundedbold";
font-size: 22px;
color: #000000;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
padding-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%; 
z-index: 10; 
position: fixed; 
left: 200px; 
top: 31px; 
height: auto;}
```

Which is applied to the following div...

```
<div id="ProjectName">
<a href="design_museum.html">Design Museum</a><br />
<a href="blendings_tea.html">Blendings Tea</a><br />
<a href="europes_metros.html">Europes Metros</a><br />
<a href="letter_e.html">Letter E</a><br />
<a href="must_see.html">Must See</a><br />
<a href="torsion.html">Torsion</a><br />
<a href="arts_and_crafts_movement.html">Arts & Crafts Movement</a><br />
</div>
```

The line of text currently running over two lines is the 'Arts & Crafts Movement'.

Any advice would be excellent.

Comment: You'll get more help if you explain how it's not working as you expect and the desired behavior.

Comment: @EternalHour Currently when website is viewed on mobile the text of the 'Arts & Crafts Movement' will run across two lines. What I want to achieve is a standard line height lines of text with a line break but then where the text runs across two lines without a line break i want that line height to be smaller.

Comment: Don't use line breaks. Build a list (`<ul><li></li><li></li></ul>`) instead, and you wouldn't have had this issue to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.  Set the primary line-height on your parent `div` (`#ProjectName`), and then set `display: inline-block` for the `a` elements along with a different line-height value. Using `vertical-align: top` on the `a` elements gives a better result.

```css
#ProjectName {
  font-family: "helvetica_roundedbold";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 400px; /* to force a line break */
  z-index: 10;
  /* 
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  */
  height: auto;
  line-height: 2.0;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
#ProjectName a {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div id="ProjectName">
  <a href="design_museum.html">Design Museum</a><br />
  <a href="blendings_tea.html">Blendings Tea</a><br />
  <a href="europes_metros.html">Europes Metros</a><br />
  <a href="letter_e.html">Letter E</a><br />
  <a href="must_see.html">Must See</a><br />
  <a href="torsion.html">Torsion</a><br />
  <a href="arts_and_crafts_movement.html">Arts & Crafts Movement</a><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the line-height for the links.

```
#ProjectName a{line-height: 30px;}
```

You can make the line-height whichever size suites you.

You can use a media query to have different css for when the screen is a certain size. ie.

`@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { css code here.... }`

The css code in that media query will only run when the screen size is 500px or less. You can change the 500px to the screen size when line-height needs to change.

Comment: I don't think that would tackle the issue. What I want to achieve is a standard line height for lines of text with a line break but then where the text runs across two lines without a line break i want that line height to be smaller.

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if it helps for what you are looking for.